# Place div on top of a <li> and <a> without moving their position

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to place a circlular div `(border-radius:85)` on top of a `<li><a></a></li>` to make something like this:

[image]

Now making it on only one box its kinda working although when I have 30 or more boxes placed next to each other, it forces them to change position and not align properly.

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZtbTU/

If you remove the circular div you'll notice that the boxes are aligned properly.

**How can place the circular div on all boxes without affecting the boxes position?**

Comment: changing position to absolute of the div work have here is what u wants http://jsfiddle.net/ZtbTU/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/vmqZ9/).

I added `position: absolute` to the circular div. I then removed `overflow: hidden` and added some `top` and `left` definitions to position the div.

**html**

```
<ul>
   <li id="item-1">
      <a href="#" ></a><div class="kshort">1</div>
   </li>
   <li id="item-2">
      <a href="#" ></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
ul li{
    float:left;
    margin:12px;
    position:relative}

ul li a{
    background:#ccc;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block;
    height:48px;
    width:48px}

div {
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background:#333;
    color:white;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:absolute;
    line-height:14px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    top: 35px;
    left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/kartikrao/tZmnz/4/

Edit : fiddle updated to place the div at the bottom

Comment: only 3 lines of css used to accomplish what you need :)

Comment: Edit the answer so I can remove the -1.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/LFPgf/11/

Answer (score -1):

I change the `div` css to use `.kshort`, removed `overflow:hidden` from `.kshort` and `ul li` and changed the positioning of the `.kshort` div to use `top` and `left` and not `margin-top` and `margin-left`. Do this and you get:

http://jsfiddle.net/fFPbx/1/